# Как с помощью плагина animate.css анимировать progress bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, frontend, progress-bar

Мне нужно, чтобы при скроле сайта, дойдя до прогресс бара, он анимировался (увеличивались проценты).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" style="width: 90%;" aria-valuenow="90%" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
            <div class="progress-point"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.progress {
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #e9eaea;
    overflow: visible;
}

.progress {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    font-size: .75rem;
    border-radius: .25rem;
}

.progress-bar .progress-point {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #facd49;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(136, 177, 69, .1);
    position: relative;
    right: -7px;
}

.progress-bar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007bff;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь библиотекой [wow.js](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW), которая включает анимацию, когда скролл достигает анимируемый блок. Здесь можно [увидеть пример работы](http://master-css.com/demo/WOWjs/).